# How can I call function inside Linq to Entities query?

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following code:

```
  public ActionResult Getinfobyid(int id)
    {
        //var req = db.td_adherent.Include(u => u.td_company).ToList();
        LoginSecretAttribute l = new LoginSecretAttribute();
        var req = from a in db.table 
                  join u in db.table2 on a.table1_id equals u.table2_id into us 
                  from u in us.DefaultIfEmpty()
                  select new
                  {
                     u = new
                    {
                       name = l.Decrypt(u.name),
                    }
                  }
        return Json(req, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

I need to execute function Decrypt

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are calling `ToList` or `ToArray` before calling `select` with custom function

```
    var req = (from a in db.table 
              join u in db.table2 on a.table1_id equals u.table2_id into us 
              from u in us.DefaultIfEmpty()).ToList();


     var req2 = from x in req
             select new
                {
                    u = new
                    {
                        name = l.Decrypt(x.name),
                    }
                }
```

Reason for that is: LINQ to SQL is LazyLoaded until you actually access it's results. When you do `ToList`, `ToArray`, `FirstOrDefault`, 'AsEnumerable' etc it actually calls db and gets data. At that point there is no more `LINQtoSQL` and become `LINQtoObjects` which allows you to use any methods you need.

Please keep in mind that after execution `LINQtoObjects` works in Memory. So all the data are already downloaded from db.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AsEnumerable` so that your method will be called in code instead of your Linq provider trying to convert it to SQL.

```
public ActionResult Getinfobyid(int id)
{
    //var req = db.td_adherent.Include(u => u.td_company).ToList();
    LoginSecretAttribute l = new LoginSecretAttribute();
    var req = (from a in db.table 
               join u in db.table2 on a.table1_id equals u.table2_id into us 
               from u in us.DefaultIfEmpty()
               select u.name).AsEnumerable()
               .Select(n => new
               {
                   u = new
                   {
                       name = l.Decrypt(n),
                   }
               });
    return Json(req, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```